# Performance issue running mongodb aggregation

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to run a query that joins documents from two collections, I wrote an aggregation query but it takes too much time when running in the production database with many documents. Is there any way to write this query in a more efficient way?

Query in Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dLb3hsJHNYt

There are two collections **users** and **activities**. I need to run a query to get some users (from **users** collection), and also their last activity (from **activities** collection).

**Database:**

```
db={
    "users": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "username": "user1",
        "country": "BR",
        "creation_date": 1646873628
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "username": "user2",
        "country": "US",
        "creation_date": 1646006402
      }
    ],
    "activities": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "activity": "like",
        "timestamp": 1647564787
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "activity": "comment",
        "timestamp": 1647564834
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "activity": "like",
        "timestamp": 1647564831
      }
    ]
}
```

**Inefficient Query:**

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
      // Get users using some filters
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$not": { "$in": [ "$country", [ "AR", "CA" ] ] } },
            { "$gte": [ "$creation_date", 1646006400 ] },
            { "$lte": [ "$creation_date", 1648684800 ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      // Get the last activity within the time range
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "activities",
        "as": "last_activity",
        "let": { "cur_email": "$email" },
        "pipeline": [
          {
            "$match": {
              "$expr": {
                 "$and": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$email", "$$cur_email" ] },
                    { "$gte": [ "$timestamp", 1647564787 ] },
                    { "$lte": [ "$timestamp", 1647564834 ] }
                 ]
              }
            }
          },
          { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1 } },
          { "$limit": 1 }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      // Remove users with no activity
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$gt": [ { "$size": "$last_activity" }, 0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "country": "BR",
        "creation_date": 1.646873628e+09,
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "last_activity": [
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "activity": "comment",
            "email": "user1@gmail.com",
            "timestamp": 1.647564788e+09
        }
        ],
        "username": "user1"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "country": "US",
        "creation_date": 1.646006402e+09,
        "email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "last_activity": [
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "activity": "like",
            "email": "user2@gmail.com",
            "timestamp": 1.647564831e+09
        }
        ],
        "username": "user2"
    }
]
```

I'm more familiar with relational databases, so I'm struggling a little to run this query efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: First, you dont need the usage of `$expr` in the initial `$match` stage (using `$expr` can sometimes may not apply indexes). And, indexing on the fields (maybe a Compound Index on `users` fields) used in the initial match stage filter can benefit in terms of performance. Also, see [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).

Comment: MongoDB 5 supports index use with `$expr` for operators like `$eq` and comparisons like `$gt`, but try to remove them, you dont need the `$expr`, also use the query `$nin` . Also use lookup without let, you dont need it, use the new version of mongoDB 5, with localfield,foreign field + pipeline. Create index in for the first match, also create index on the foreight field in the lookup, and benchmark again.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up making two queries and post processing in the code. Not the best approach but it solved the problem for now.